# Horizontal scrollbar not scrolling

Tags: html, css, sass, containers

Been stuck on this forever! I looked at most of the sources I've found that had a similar issue, and tried multiple approaches but still can't seem to solve the issue.

I'm trying to create a horizontal card scroller but whatever approach I try the scrollbar appears and the content doesn't overflow my space but it just won't scroll horizontally.

My CSS

```css
.media-scroller {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 45%;
  overscroll-behavior-inline: contain;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.card img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 120px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.mid {
  margin-top: 25%;
}

.list-group-item {
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  color: var(--main-color);
  border: none;
}

.card-title {
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  color: var(--main-color);
}
```

My HTML

```
<div class="media-scroller">
    <div class="card bg-transparent">
        <img src="/main/assets/images/oak.png" class="card-img-top" alt="oak">
        <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Oak</h5>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Durability</li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Beautiful texture</li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Water resistance</li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Expensive</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card mid bg-transparent">
        <img src="/main/assets/images/bulk.png" class="card-img-top" alt="buk">
        <div class="card-body mid">
        <h5 class="card-title">Buk</h5>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Durability</li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Hard to handle</li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent"> 1 </li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent"> 2 </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-transparent">
        <img src="/main/assets/images/ash.png" class="card-img-top" alt="ash">
        <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Ash</h5>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush bg-transparent">
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Durability</li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Hard to handle</li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Ideal for flooring</li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Great Resistnace</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, it's working. Maybe you have to check the remaining part of the CSS for further debugging.

```css
.media-scroller {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 45%;
  overscroll-behavior-inline: contain;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.card img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 120px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.mid {
  margin-top: 25%;
}

.list-group-item {
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  color: var(--main-color);
  border: none;
}

.card-title {
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  color: var(--main-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="media-scroller">
    <div class="card bg-transparent">
        <img src="/main/assets/images/oak.png" class="card-img-top" alt="oak">
        <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Oak</h5>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Durability</li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Beautiful texture</li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Water resistance</li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Expensive</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card mid bg-transparent">
        <img src="/main/assets/images/bulk.png" class="card-img-top" alt="buk">
        <div class="card-body mid">
        <h5 class="card-title">Buk</h5>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Durability</li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Hard to handle</li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent"> 1 </li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent"> 2 </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-transparent">
        <img src="/main/assets/images/ash.png" class="card-img-top" alt="ash">
        <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Ash</h5>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush bg-transparent">
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Durability</li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Hard to handle</li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Ideal for flooring</li>
        <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Great Resistnace</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit:

Given the [link](https://github.com/deividask13/Wood-Service-Products), I'm adding

```
.menu,.nav-wrapper{
 height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You were right :) So what happened was I had a menu that had visibility set to hidden while the checkbox wasn't checked and once checked set the visibility of the menu to visible. But now I run into the issue where It still takes up space on the screen not allowing to click anywhere hence why it won't let me scroll horizontally.

Comment: You're welcome. :-) Do you have a publicly available version to see it?

Comment: Yeah sure, here is my GitHub https://github.com/deividask13/Wood-Service-Products don't judge too much my first project for the course I'm doing :)) Designed for mobile phones first (iPhone 12) haven't made it responsive yet but will do it soon.